# Nested Folder Dynamic Component - Laravel Blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Trying to use a dynamic component in order to pass in a variable and get to the component file I need. However, the component files are nested in another folder inside the components folder. I'm unable to do the normal `<x-foldername.file />` since it is a dynamic component.

Is there a different way to go into a subfolder using dynamic components? Below is an example of the component call I'm currently doing that won't work with the file in the subfolder.

`<x-dynamic-component :component="$component_variable" :data="$data"  />`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I figured it out.

```
<x-dynamic-component :component="'foldername.' . $component_variable" :data="$data"/>
```

Comment: Great find, I spent about half an hour trying to do something similar with a partially dynamic component name, and this did the trick. Not sure how performant it is, but I'll take it.